# Непонятные знаки при чтении данных из файла

Tags: java

У меня есть два *.txt*-файла, с которых я читаю данные.

Файл №1:

```
7879
lab_1.docx  18
```

Файл №2:

```
6431
```

Идея в том, что во второй файл записываются `id` уже обработанных файлов.
Надо перебором проверять на наличие `id` и что-то делать.

```
for (; scannerTmp.hasNext(); ) {  
    id_found = false; 
    line =  scannerTmp.nextLine();  
    mName = scannerTmp.nextLine();  
    mPages = scannerTmp.nextLine();  
    while (scannerId.hasNext()) {  
        line2 = scannerId.nextLine();  
        System.out.println(line.toString() + "+" + line2.toString());  
        if (line.toString().equals(line2.toString())) {  
            id_found = true;  
            break; 
        }
```

Вот что получается на выходе:

```
п»ї7879+6431
```

Откуда берутся эти непонятные знаки?

Comment: п»ї - маркер последовательности байтов у файлов в UTF-8, см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) UTF-8 отображаемый в кодировке cp-1251.
Сохраните файлы без BOM (эта опция есть в любом нормальном текстовом редакторе).

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало